# recv() and recvfrom() methods for TCP

Tags: python, tcp, udp, recv, recvfrom

Why does **TCP** `socket.recvfrom()` not return the sender address as it does with UDP?

When does TCP socket.recv()  an empty string?

Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language or library are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does TCP `socket.recvfrom()` not return the sender address as it does with UDP?

Because once a TCP connection is established that address does not change. That is the address that was passed to `connect` or received from `accept` calls. You can also find out the peer's address (if you lost it somehow) with `getpeername`.

> When does TCP socket.recv() an empty string?

When the peer has closed the connection and no more data will be coming in. You can still send data though because TCP connections can be half-closed.

Comment: Thanks!...  I am using python

Comment: @user3109117 I know that you are using Python. Learn how to use this web-site though.

Comment: You *may* be still able to send data, *if* the peer has half-closed the connection.

Comment: @EJP If there was an `RST` segment `recv()` returns an error. That means if `recv()` returns an empty string that was a `FIN` and the connection is half-open.

Comment: @EJP You are right that the peer could have `close`d the connection though. There is no way to tell that from `FIN` alone.